# mysql object not converting to int

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a wp mysql db column as following:

```
`update_number` =  int(11) Null:No, default:0
```

Then i have the following php:

```
$RSS_UPDATE = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT update_number FROM $table WHERE sub_id = $post_id");
if ( $RSS_UPDATE )
{
    foreach ( $RSS_UPDATE as $RSS_SINGLE )
    {
        $RSS_ROW_NEW  = $RSS_SINGLE + 1;            
        $wpdb->update($table, array('update_number' => $RSS_ROW_NEW),array( 'sub_id' => $post_id ));    
    }   
}
```

So the idea is that, for any results that the `sub_id = $post_id`, then get all the `update_number`. (ie. could be "0,2,1,4,2,2")

Then, for each value, I want to increase the integer value by +1 and update it.

However, i am getting `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int`.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: inside the loop do as `var_dump($RSS_SINGLE); exit;` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to ensure $RSS_SINGLE is string or int

var_dump($RSS_SINGLE);exit;

```js
$RSS_UPDATE = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT update_number FROM $table WHERE sub_id = $post_id");
if ( $RSS_UPDATE )
{
    foreach ( $RSS_UPDATE as $RSS_SINGLE )
    {
        $RSS_ROW_NEW  = $RSS_SINGLE->update_number + 1;            
        $wpdb->update($table, array('update_number' => $RSS_ROW_NEW),array( 'sub_id' => $post_id ));    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but how do I properly use `var_dump($RSS_SINGLE);exit;`? where do I see the result? Is there a way to show in `debug` file?

Comment: before $RSS_ROW_NEW  = $RSS_SINGLE->update_number + 1;